# How to compare Logged user related association with other users inside context builder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

i will add code first then i will explain what i want from code

```
namespace App\Serializer;


use ApiPlatform\Core\Serializer\SerializerContextBuilderInterface;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class UserCollectorContextBuilder implements SerializerContextBuilderInterface
{

    private SerializerContextBuilderInterface $decorated;
    private AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker;
    private TokenStorageInterface $token;


    public function __construct(
        SerializerContextBuilderInterface $decorated,
        AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker,
        TokenStorageInterface $token
    )
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function createFromRequest(Request $request, bool $normalization, array $extractedAttributes = null): array
    {
        $context = $this->decorated->createFromRequest($request, $normalization, $extractedAttributes);
        $resourceClass = $context['resource_class'] ?? null;

        if (
            $resourceClass === User::class &&
            isset($context['groups']) &&
            $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') &&
            $normalization === true
        ){
            $context['groups'][] = 'admin:read';

        }

        return $context;
    }
}
```

User Entity properties

```
/**
  * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
  * @Groups("admin:read")
  */
private bool $enabled = false;
/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Association", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
  * @Groups({"user:read"})
  */
private ?Association $association = null;
```

so the above code is working it show the enabled value to Admin but what i want is that admin sees only users enabled value from the same group (association) as admin not from other group because each group (association) is having their own Admin.

i would be glad if someone could help how to achieve this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i achieved what i wanted with custom Normalizer thank you.
because we can't have object inside context builder

[enter link description here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/)